K8S + Linkerd2: When deploying pods to Linkerd2's mesh, is it harmful to include injecting "tap"?
When I deploy a pod in Kubernetes, there is an annotation, "linkerd.io/inject: enabled", that adds the pod to linkerd2's mesh.  I have not found any information indicating that by default adding the annotation, "linkerd.io/tap: enabled", is a bad practice or would be harmful.  Does anyone know the answer?
